# How to re-render react functional component when a promise is resolved

Tags: reactjs, typescript, functional-programming, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out a simple todo app in react using typescript. the newly created todo doesn't reflect on the list. am trying to figure out what went wrong here

my react component

```
const service = new TodoService();

function App() {

  useEffect(()=>{
    service.getAllTodos();
  }); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <TodoContainer items={service.allTodos} onNewTodoCreated={description => {service.createTodo(description)}} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the TodoContainer takes list of items and newtodoCreated as props

and my service

```
export default class TodoService {
    public allTodos: TodoItem[] = [
        {dateCreated: new Date(), id: v4(), description: "Fetch Milk" },
        {dateCreated: new Date(), id: v4(), description: "Buy iPhone" },
        {dateCreated: new Date(), id: v4(), description: "Impress at DWIT" },
    ]
    
    getAllTodos(): Promise<TodoItem[]> {
        return new Promise<TodoItem[]>((resolve) => {
             setTimeout(() => resolve(this.allTodos), 3000);
        });
    }

    createTodo(description: string): Promise<TodoItem> {

        return new Promise<TodoItem>((resolve) => {
            const id = uuidv4();
            const dateCreated = new Date();
            setTimeout(() => {
                const saved = {description, id, dateCreated};
                this.allTodos.push(saved);
                resolve(saved);
            }, 2000);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook here, something like so

```js
function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    service.getAllTodos()
      .then(todos => setTodos(todos));
  }, []);

  const handleCreate = (description) => 
     service.createTodo(description)
       .then(todo => { /* @TODO update state */ })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <TodoContainer
           items={todos}
           onNewTodoCreated={handleCreate} />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```